# SVM Vs Deep Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, svm

I am trying to solve a regression problem by comparing different machine learning algorithms. So far i have tried Linear Regression) (accuracy: 0.88) and SVM ( Accuarcy : 0.84). Now i am trying to neural network for the same problem but i am getting a very low accuracy ( around 1 Percent!) I cant seem to figure out if i am using the same data, then why am i getting such low acccuracy using the neural network?
I have tried using different number of neurons but nothing seems to work. Here is the neural network that i am using [Neural Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1c2P.png)
I expect the accuracy to be somewhere near to SVM and linear regression but it does not seem to work. My labels look like this [labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUj8p.png)
My features look like this. [features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTYc0.png).Here is the output of the neural network [Neural Network Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwdCw.png)

Comment: you should add some details to get attention from stackoverflow geeks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing a regression task on your data, accuracy is a classification metric and can only be used for classification, not regression, so your results are meaningless and you cannot compare regressors using accuracy.

Just use another metric like mean squared error or mean absolute error.